# Postgres won't start after reboot on Linux

Tags: postgresql

I am running postgres 12 and it won't start after server reboot (run manually by `reboot`). The attached EBS volume has not changed and I don't see any evidence of a data loss.

When I run psql, I get (this used to work before restart)

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres 
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


pg_lsclusters does not help - 

    pg_lsclusters 12 main start
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
    12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

The error in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log is

```
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2021-03-01 00:33:24.976 UTC [1866] FATAL:  could not access file "anon": No such file or directory
2021-03-01 00:33:24.976 UTC [1866] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

When I start postgres, I don't get any error -

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t want to start PostgreSQL manually every time your Linux restarts, run the following command :

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable
```

If it can not find LSB script then do this :

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

Comment: thanks but it still didn't work  - my postgres isn't starting .. ```   pg_lsclusters 12 main start
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log```